# Fabric.js blend mode - blended image is black

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to use the blend filter in fabric.js, and can't spot what am I doing wrong : the image on which the filter is applied becomes black

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

var bgImg = fabric.Image.fromURL('url', function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
}, {
    crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
});

var blendImg = fabric.Image.fromURL('url', function (oImg) {
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Blend({
        image: bgImg,
        mode: 'multiply',
        alpha:0.5
    });
   oImg.filters.push(filter);
    oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    canvas.add(oImg);
}, {
    crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
});
```

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mikado/5Lg7nos6/1/, please hint me up.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into **async** issues. The code is making external requests for images, and a callback structure needs to implemented.

I'm not sure what exactly you want the image to look like... but I have changed up the structure of your code to get it to work.

Based off of what you had: we grab the first image, then add it to the canvas, then we grab the second image and apply a blend filter to it. We then add the second image to the canvas.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Grey_Tshirt.jpg', function(oImg) {

    canvas.add(oImg);

    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Blend({
        image: oImg,
        mode: 'multiply',
        alpha: 0.3
    });

    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg', function(zImg) {

        zImg.filters.push(filter);
        zImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

        canvas.add(zImg);

    },{crossOrigin: ''});


},{crossOrigin: ''});
```

heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lg7nos6/2/